Random hardware freezes / shutdowns
I recently acquired a second hand desktop. I installed a Debian Bookworm on it.
I'm getting two kinds of random hardware issues:

freeze (no ping, no SSH, no Magic SysRq keys)
shutdown or reboot

Nothing in the logs.
I opened the case to check everything is cool, even removed the CPU fan and checked the CPU is cool too. I also added the sensors app to my desktop panel to confirm everything's fine (except it says the SSD is constantly at 82°C but this is clearly wrong, the SSD is cool).
I checked RAM with memcheck. I even ran the computer with half the RAM and the issue happened with both halves.
Hardware specs:

AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor          Unknown CPU @ 3.4GHz
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] (rev cf)
24 GB RAM
28 GB swap (empty)
240 GB SSD for /
1 TB HDD for /home

I installed latest BIOS (F56) before setting up the computer. It appears it has vanished from the download page so I just installed the new one (F66) but the problem persists.
Any idea which part could be responsible for this? I already ruled out the RAM. I can swap the graphic card with an old one for a while. Swapping MB or CPU is another story (I'd need to buy new ones) and I'd try that only with good reasons to believe it will succeed.
(I posted on Unix & Linux hoping I could get help troubleshooting this from the OS but to no avail. And apparently, strictly hardware question are more suited here.)
Edit
I've read about issues with this MB and found hints:

Disable C-states and AMD Cool & Quiet in the BIOS.

People have had issues when using RAM with different frequencies. It should work fine (at the lowest speed) but people have been reporting issues. Those could be due to incompatibilities other than different freq, though.


I've removed the two 4GB to keep only the two 8 GB of the same model and I'll see how it goes.
BTW after the change, only one of the two was detected and while looking closer I slightly touched one of them which resulted in the same kind of reboot. I'm wondering if the problem could be due to a bad fit or a defective RAM socket.
If I still get issues, I'll try to disable the power saving options in the BIOS as suggested.

Try running from a live Linux distro on USB to rule out drive-associated issues. Also check if the hardware was overclocked -- might be unstable.

Yes @DrMoishePippik, good point about the live distro to rule out the drive. I don't think the HW was overcloked. Not sure how to check that (except by resetting the BIOS to defaults).
